# How can I change meta key from alt to cmd on Mac in Emacs 24?

Tags: macos, emacs

I've downloaded [Emacs 24 pretest](http://emacsformacosx.com/builds) for Mac OS X according to the **[emacs starter kit](https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit)** guide. Before I've been using [Carbon Emacs](http://homepage.mac.com/zenitani/emacs-e.html) as the version 1 of starter kit recommends, but version 2 does requires me to upgrade Emacs 24.

The problem is, that in Carbon Emacs, it is <kbd>cmd</kbd> that is used for the meta key, but in Emacs 24 pretest, I have to use <kbd>alt</kbd> instead.

Is there any simple way to change the keybinding, or do I have to chose another version?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use the following,

```
 (setq mac-option-modifier 'super)
 (setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)
```

Comment: This is useful, but Antti's Honkela's answer has the advantage of preserving the default option key behavior of OS X (which is useful for inputting certain important characters, at least on some non-US keyboard).

Answer (score 25):

If you use an international keyboard that uses option for composing special characters, you should add the following code to your .emacs:

```
(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)
(setq mac-option-modifier nil)
```

Comment: For non-US keyboard, is better to have alt as nil so that we can write symbols as ~. Many thanks

Answer (score 21):

If you like to use the same configuration on multiple different computers that aren't all running OSX like I do, then here's a possible solution:

```
(when (eq system-type 'darwin)
  (setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)
  (setq mac-option-modifier nil))
```

This way it'll only attempt to set <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> if you're actually on a Mac

Comment: Hi! Do you happen to know how to make these permanent? The problem I have is that every time after restarting Emacs I have to evaluate this command. I mean it *is* in my `.emacs.d/init.el`, but doesn't automatically work.

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep digging

Comment: It is probably better to use `(eq window-system 'ns)` as the test -- that way you can use the same init file with both an Emacs built for X11 (e.g. running with either with a local XQuartz server, or with some other remote X server) and one built for NextStep (i.e. macOS native).